# How to obtain the exact p-value of a Kruskal-Wallis test in R?

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis

How to obtain the exact p-value of a Kruskal-Wallis (e.g. with 3 groups) test in R?

Example of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    dv = c(0.80, 0.83, 1.89, 1.04, 1.45, 1.38, 1.91, 1.64, 0.73, 1.46,
           1.15, 0.88, 0.90, 0.74, 1.21),
    group = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(5, 5, 5))))
```

I tried the `coin` package using the function `kruskal_test`

```
kruskal_test(dv ~ group, data = df,distribution= "exact")
```

Although an error is produced:

```
Error in .local(object, ...) : ‘object’ is not a two-sample problem
```

If I change the `"exact"` for `"approximate"` it runs, but it is not the exact distribution...

Any thoughts?

Comment: perhaps you need a pair wise test

Comment: Try `combn(levels(df$group), 2, FUN = function(x) kruskal_test(dv ~ group, data = subset(df, group %in% x), distribution = 'exact'), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: Have you tried `stats::kruskal.test(dv ~ group, data = df)`?

Comment: @duckmayr, yes sorry, you are correct, I somehow got confused for a moment between `kruskal.test` and `ks.test`. I too had success with your `kruskal.test` approach.

Comment: No worries @IanCampbell ! We all get turned around from time to time

Comment: Yes, it does the chi-square approximation.

I saw in [this](https://doi.org/10.1080/00220973.2012.699904) 2013 that no package does it... but I would like to know if someone already implemented it (besides the SPSS's `exact` module...

Comment: Ah, I understand now your issue @Sinval , my apologies. I do not know of a solution to your exact issue, sorry

Comment: @Sinval I looked around a bit and to my knowledge there isn't an implementation of an exact algorithm for > 2 groups in R yet. Algorithms for it are presented though, for example in https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/SAC-120023876 , so it might be possible to implement yourself if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks, it really seems that it is not yet implemented in R. :/

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error is because you can only exactly calculate the distribtution for a two-sample problem.

From `help("kruskal_test")`:

> ...the distribution can be approximated via Monte Carlo resampling or computed exactly for univariate two-sample problems by setting distribution to "approximate" or "exact" respectively.

Comment: Well, if I set to `"approximate"` it does work. So that is only true for the `"exact"` option.

Comment: @Sinval I found some papers talking about the SAS exact approach, but I couldn't find anything implemented in R. If this answer isn't helpful, I can delete it.

Comment: Thank you, I know that `IBM SPSS Statistics Exact  Tests` module also manages to obtain those exact p-values. I really wanted to use R because of the `exams` package I' using with my students. I want them to check the exact p-values table, and then insert them in the Moodle exam platform. After the values will be compared with those produced with R...